# Showing that all irreducibles are prime in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ without passing to $\mathbb{Q}[x]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals, irreducible-polynomials

The usual proof that irreducibles are prime in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ uses Gauss's lemma to show that a polynomial with content 1 that is irreducible over $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ is also irreducible over
$\mathbb{Q}[x]$. Then you can use that $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ is a PID to show that every ideal generated by an irreducible $p$ is maximal, from which it follows that $\mathbb{Z}[x]/\langle p \rangle$ is an ID and thus $p$ is prime in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$.

Is there a way to show that every irreducible is prime in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ without "going" through $\mathbb{Q}$? You can show that $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ is an ID and has the ACCP directly (since it inherits these from $\mathbb{Z}$). But these are definitely not enough (indeed $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$ also satisfies these properties but not all irreducibles are primes), so what makes $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ "special"?

Some added context: this comes from a homework question where I'm tasked with showing that $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ has the ACCP and that every irreducible is prime, in order to prove that it's an UFD. I know how to prove that irreducibles are prime by assuming that $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ is an UFD / by passing to $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ - I was wondering if one could avoid using unique factorisations in order to prove that irreducibles are prime.

---

Edit: The question this was flagged as being a duplicate of concerns itself with showing that factorial rings are AP-rings ("atoms are prime", so basically what I'm asking here). What I'm specifically asking is whether or not there is a way to prove that $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ is an AP-ring without involving $\mathbb{Q}[x]$, so unless somebody provides a proof of $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ being factorial that does not involve $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ / gives some heuristic reason as for why you're forced to pass to the field of fractions, I don't see how this question can possibly be a duplicate.

Comment: @paulblartmathcop I think the OP knows this fact, and the question is trying to avoid showing that $\mathbb{Z}[X]$ is a UFD to prove the result in the title. (After all, how do you show that $\mathbb{Z}[X]$ is a UFD without Gauss' lemma?)

Comment: @Alex that's right, I've added some more context to the question.

Comment: We are assuming that the polynomial has leading coefficient $1$ [as opposed to merely the coefficients having a common factor], is that correct. Otherwise, what about the polynomial $p^nx^n-q^n$ in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$, where $p,q$ are distinct primes, and $n$ is odd.

Comment: @Mike I'm not sure I understand. $p^n x^n - q^n$ is not irreducible over $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ : it factors as $(px - q) \cdot \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} (px)^k q^{n-1-k}$

Comment: Yes, my mistake!